# Android AsyncHttpClient download image file with Content-Type: unkonwn header

Tags: android, http, http-headers, content-type, content-disposition

I'm using the AsyncHttpClient library from http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ and have it calling web services fine to retrieve JSON responses. I'm now trying to call a web service that streams files back to the client over HTTP. I'm therefore using the BinaryHttpResponseHandler to capture the byte[] data returned. The code I'm using:

```
public static void getImage(Context context, String url, final ImageLoadingListener listener) {
    boolean online = isOnline(context);
    client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    if (online) {
        String[] allowedContentTypes = new String[]{"image/png", "image/jpeg"};
        client.getHttpClient().getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);
        client.get(Html.fromHtml(url).toString(), new BinaryHttpResponseHandler(allowedContentTypes) {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                listener.imageReceived(bmp);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
                printRequestResult(i, headers);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However when I try to download image file with header Content-Type: set as "unknown" it fails, and when examining the Throwable object the exception is  'org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Content-Type not allowed! '.

Image I try to download is: http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/Engadget/opHNMlIEDUj72LqIRjgU66Z9ddGI6_GjULpJJpg0iuQSUUUNT-wpyKA5LlWCaHw09N_KlKFNU55j81P6QLhOYwScbeX0ABeo_SL1cmNn4KEHqfL8of0dGpp1h9_2ZbgkT1PYJGuil5bt2uyYbpyXYDdCcCtFmm9Vdmvnd93dEwVY9DygmaXajJcYNj1vwPg-fbQaTqFe6Dv5GKmTm-PRaJNTzFzfOTzLDRYvDH1nQEk

If it is properly displayed in browser, is there any way to download it using AsyncHttpClient library?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to come round Content-type check by specifying:

```
String[] allowedContentTypes = new String[]{".*"};
```

I guess it is not the best solution, cause it just turns out Content-type check, but this is the best I could come up with